# Google Maps API v3 - changed in the last week or so?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, geocoding

I was using the following code to obtain the lat and lng values from user input. It seemed to be working fine, until just recently.

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var lat = parseFloat(results[0].geometry.location.wa).toFixed(3);
    var lng = parseFloat(results[0].geometry.location.xa).toFixed(3);
    ....
```

Now if I console.log `results[0].geometry.location` I get `(51.4793388, -2.5933342) { va=51.4793388, wa=-2.5933342}`.

It appears as if `xa` has changed to `va`. **What is the correct way to reference these values?**

Comment: the google maps api library is minified. Thus the variable names are often shortened to a random set of characters. You shouldn't approach the x and y through these variables but through their getters: ie. lat() and lng() to avoid the same issue with future versions.

Comment: that makes a lot more sense! cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently ran into the same issue on my Google Map API 3.0 application.  Basically, the wa and xa variables if i remember correctly are just LatLng() variables.  So you can call them this way:

```
results[0].geometry.location.lat().toFixed(3);
results[0].geometry.location.lng().toFixed(3);
```

where va = lat and wa = lng

Comment: thanks to your question i corrected my web app too =D cheers back! woot woot!